# Setup backend server side scheduler to identify clients and run web application at a scheduled time

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-chrome, webapi

i have a quiz web application running on a server and written in php and connected to mysql database
there is a request to have the application run as an app by running a batch file or this line on the client system START Chrome.exe --app="http://survey.peterinnovations.net/quiz"

WinRM is not enabled on the client systems but they are all on a corporate networkk, i want to know how to be able to achieve this

1. Identify the clients that call up the application and also b able to push the script or command to the clients to run the application at any time - more like a push notification that will load the page

Comment: This sounds less like a programming question and more like a sysadmin question? It's also a bit too unspecific and broad.

Comment: can you not extend the cmd line argument for starting the quiz to include their username &/or computername via standard system variables (%username% etc)

Comment: Hello , i can but all these will be from a remote system which will require a local admin privilege to run the command on the remote systems

Comment: Not sure I folllow: To launch the quiz you use either a batch file ( easy to edit, one edit affects everyone ) or via shortcut. How is that shortcut deployed to the end user? If I were me I'd do it via Group Policy but again, a singe shortcut modified to include username / computer as arguments to the PHP quiz should be quite simple?!

Comment: Hello Ramraider, you are saying its better to deploy a shortcut to clients systems, i think this can be done, but i dont know how to achieve getting the details of the workstation and also be able to send a command to the remote clients to launch the shortcut at a particular time